# Someone knows a xml2bibtex or other *2bibtex converters?

Tags: bibtex, xml

I have a database of the books in a [BookCat](http://www.fnprg.com/bookcat/helpfile/index.html?intro_gettingstarted.htm) (`.mdb`-format), but now I want to convert `BookCat`-database into `bibtex`, but `BookCat` can not export  directly into `bibtex` but only into `xml`. So, I need converter, or suitable advice.

Comment: http://ctan.org/topic/bibtex-util

Comment: @cfr the only XML-related thing catalogued as `bibtex-util` is designed to convert _to_ XML.  faced with the OP’s problem is probably to write something from scratch using some script’s XML processing library (there‘s several for perl).

Comment: @wasteofspace It was only a suggestion to look there. `bibutils` converts between various formats but I don't know which (except bibtex and RIS).

Comment: XQuery or XSLT would be good candidates for this job. For example, by using BaseX, you could first develop ad hoc queries in order to get a good overview of the XML data, and then implement a full conversion that serializes to BibTeX. Is there already an XML syntax for classic BibTeX? There is one for BibLaTeX (Biber converts to it), but I don’t know how well this would map (I don’t use classic BibTeX myself).